# Separating a column in R using Regex & separate (tidyr)

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

This is what I am looking to be able to do.
https://regex101.com/r/KchccA/1

I want to match on any characters in-between = and ) while also considering if there is a null captured group, as I want all fields to be populated per row.

Example of a row: In this example Address4, County, and Contact name are null.  You can also see how some have wrong / incorrect values. **Theres also some initial / ending text too I need to remove.**

```
x <- "Please enter an UT location before booking the order.. ADDRESS_VALIDATION_FAILED (SITE_TYPE=uct) (SITE_USE_ID=1000) (CUSTOMER_NAME=cname) (CUSTOMER_NUMBER=2000) (ADDRESS1=addy1) (ADDRESS2=addy2) (ADDRESS3=addy3) (ADDRESS4=) (CITY=.) (STATE=) (ZIP=0000) (COUNTY=) (COUNTRY=NO) (CONTACT_NAME=) The task is raised for line_number: 7"
```

However in R when I try to utilize tidyr's separate method I end up with undesirable results. Am I not escaping it right?

Here was my code for it:

```
df.sub <- separate(data = main.data, col = Order.Task.Text.CCW, into = c("SITE_TYPE", "SITE_USE_ID", "CUSTOMER_NAME","CUSTOMER_NUMBER", "ADDRESS1", "ADDRESS2", "ADDRESS3", "ADDRESS4", "CITY", "STATE", "ZIP", "COUNTY", "COUNTRY", "CONTACT_NAME"), sep = "=([^\\)]+|())\\)")
```

Example of Results:

```
   SITE_TYPE    SITE_USE_ID   CUSTOMER_NAME      CUSTOMER_NUMBER       
1  (SITE_TYPE    (SITE_USE_ID    (CUSTOMER_NAME  (CUSTOMER_NUMBER
2  (SITE_TYPE    (SITE_USE_ID    (CUSTOMER_NAME  (CUSTOMER_NUMBER
3  (SITE_TYPE    (SITE_USE_ID    (CUSTOMER_NAME  (CUSTOMER_NUMBER
4  (SITE_TYPE    (SITE_USE_ID    (CUSTOMER_NAME  (CUSTOMER_NUMBER
```

---

### Final Solution

Here's my final solution for anyone curious, based on correct answer formatted for ease of viewing.

```
p <- proto(
 pre = function(.) .$k <- 0,
 fun = function(., x) {
 if (x == "(") .$k <- .$k + 1 else if (x == ")") .$k <- .$k - 1
 if (x == "(" && .$k == 1) "" else if (x == ")" && .$k == 0) "\n" else x
})
df.sub.final <- df.sub$text %>%
sub("^[^\\(]*\\(", "(", .) %>% 
sub("\\)[^\\)]*$", ")", .) %>% 
gsub("\n", "", .) %>%
gsub("=", ": ", .) %>%
gsubfn("([\\(\\)]) *", p, .) %>%
textConnection %>%
read.dcf %>%
as.data.frame(.)
```

Comment: Try to use positive lookhead and positive look behind. (?<=\=)([^\)]*|())(?=\))

Comment: Says Error: '\=' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""(?<=\="

Comment: (?<=\\=)([^\\)]*|())(?=\\)) try this

Comment: No didn't work, complained about the \) you have.  I tried adding \\ to all but it didn't give desired output, instead looked like: ) (SITE_USE_ID= for SITE_USE_ID field.  I think stack overflow may also need you to escape your \'s too maybe?

Comment: Try `"\\(\\w+=|\\)\\s*"`, but it might yield some empty values, I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some uncertainty as to what the valid inputs are.  Below are several different answers based on different assumptions.  All convert the input to dcf form (i.e. name: value) and then use `read.dcf`.

### !) Balanced parentheses.

Transform to dcf form (i.e. name: value).

We can handle balanced parentheses with `gsubfn`.  First create a proto object whose `pre` function initializes a counter `k` to zero and then for each match to `(` or `)` the function `fun` inputs it and increments or decrements k outputting the appropriate replacement character.  See the gsubfn package vignette for more info.

Now starting from `x` replace the junk at the beginning, replace = with : and a space and then run `gsubfn` matching ( or ) followed by optional space with the proto object we defined.  Finally read the transformed text using `read.dcf`.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(magrittr)

p <- proto(
 pre = function(.) .$k <- 0,
 fun = function(., x) {
  if (x == "(") .$k <- .$k + 1 else if (x == ")") .$k <- .$k - 1
  if (x == "(" && .$k == 1) "" else if (x == ")" && .$k == 0) "\n" else x
})

x %>%
  sub("^.*?\\(", "(", .) %>%
  gsub("=", ": ", .) %>%
  gsubfn("([\\(\\)]) *", p, .) %>%
  textConnection %>%
  read.dcf
```

### 2) Nested parentheses have no adjacent spaces

```
x <- "(SITE_TYPE=Site1) (SITE_USE_ID=2000) (CUSTOMER_NAME=cname) (CUSTOMER_NUMBER=11111) (ADDRESS1=addy1) (ADDRESS2=addy2) (ADDRESS3=addy3) (ADDRESS4=) (CITY=.) (STATE=) (ZIP=0000) (COUNTY=) (COUNTRY=NO) (CONTACT_NAME=)"


library(magrittr)

x %>%
  paste0(" ") %>%
  sub("^.*?\\(", "", .) %>%
  gsub(" +\\(", " ", .) %>%
  gsub("=", ": ", .) %>%
  gsub("\\) ", "\n", .) %>%
  textConnection %>%
  read.dcf
```

giving:

```
     SITE_TYPE SITE_USE_ID CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_NUMBER ADDRESS1 ADDRESS2
[1,] "Site1"   "2000"      "cname"       "11111"         "addy1"  "addy2" 
     ADDRESS3 ADDRESS4 CITY STATE ZIP    COUNTY COUNTRY CONTACT_NAME
[1,] "addy3"  ""       "."  ""    "0000" ""     "NO"    ""
```

### 3) fixed keywords follow the outer left parentheses.

For this one the inner parentheses can be unbalanced but the outer parentheses are always followed by one of the keywords in `cn`.

```
x <- "ADDRESS_VALIDATION_FAILED (SITE_TYPE=site1) (SITE_USE_ID=200) (CUSTOMER_NAME=abc) (CUSTOMER_NUMBER=1000) (ADDRESS1=issue here (some more text) (ADDRESS2=) (ADDRESS3=) (ADDRESS4=) (CITY=city, ) (STATE=na) (ZIP=250) (COUNTY=) (COUNTRY=NA) (CONTACT_NAME=)"

cn <- c("SITE_TYPE", "SITE_USE_ID", "CUSTOMER_NAME", "CUSTOMER_NUMBER", 
"ADDRESS1", "ADDRESS2", "ADDRESS3", "ADDRESS4", "CITY", "STATE", 
"ZIP", "COUNTY", "COUNTRY", "CONTACT_NAME")
rx <- sprintf(".(%s)", paste(cn, collapse = "|"))

x %>%
  sub("^.*?\\(", "(", .) %>%
  gsub("=", ": ", .) %>%
  gsub(rx, "\n\\1", .) %>%
  gsub("\\) *\\n", "\n", .) %>%
  sub("\\)$", "", .) %>%
  textConnection %>%
  read.dcf
```

giving:

```
     SITE_TYPE SITE_USE_ID CUSTOMER_NAME CUSTOMER_NUMBER
[1,] "site1"   "200"       "abc"         "1000"         
     ADDRESS1                     ADDRESS2 ADDRESS3 ADDRESS4 CITY    STATE
[1,] "issue here (some more text" ""       ""       ""       "city," "na" 
     ZIP   COUNTY COUNTRY CONTACT_NAME
[1,] "250" ""     "NA"    ""
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form is:

Comment: So this almost works for me, two things.  One is I have some text before and after x that I see this gsub not getting rid of, I've updated my OP (see x <-) to reflect this.  2nd how do I get this to iterate over every row in my DF (as I have ~40k of these I need to do).

Comment: Use `sub` twice. Once to remove the part before and once to remove the part afterwards. It already works for multiple rows.  For example, define x to be `x <- c(x, x)` and run the same code.

Comment: I added the following before the code above to sub the beginning and end text with just a ( and ) as needed.  See bottom of OP for full solution.

Comment: How would I stop it from gsubbing ()s within ()s? See Customer Name in this example.  
ex: x <- "Please enter an location before booking the order.. ADDRESS_VALIDATION_FAILED (SITE_TYPE=A) (SITE_USE_ID=200) (CUSTOMER_NAME=Example(),) (CUSTOMER_NUMBER=300) (ADDRESS1=addy1) (ADDRESS2=addy2) (ADDRESS3=) (ADDRESS4=) (CITY=city) (STATE=US) (ZIP=) (COUNTY=) (COUNTRY=GB) (CONTACT_NAME=)"

Comment: I have modified the code so that it replaces space( or )space. The inner parens do not have a space beside them in your example so only the outer parens will be replaced.  Also the `sub` removes junk before the first ( .

Comment: That was a good idea I tried that too, but it can have spaces ADDRESS_VALIDATION_FAILED (SITE_TYPE=A) (SITE_USE_ID=200) (CUSTOMER_NAME=Example (x) (y) z) (CUSTOMER_NUMBER=300) (ADDRESS1=addy1) (ADDRESS2=addy2) (ADDRESS3=) (ADDRESS4=) (CITY=city) (STATE=US) (ZIP=) (COUNTY=) (COUNTRY=GB) (CONTACT_NAME=)"

Comment: We can use gsubfn to count parentheses and output the appropriate replacement character. See revised answer.

Comment: You are a lifesaver!

Comment: There a way to keep an ID from another column post dplyr?  I don't know how to join it back to the orginial data. I noticed I wasn't getting quite the same #'s returned from the code, so I can't do a simple cbind.  It doesnt error in the read.dcf so not sure what causes it to not return all the lines I'm expecting.

Comment: Or maybe even add the table's ID to the text like (ID:5) to run in read.dcf?

Comment: I found the culprit, looks like nested address can have just single ( without end. Ex:
ADDRESS_VALIDATION_FAILED (SITE_TYPE=site1) (SITE_USE_ID=200) (CUSTOMER_NAME=abc) (CUSTOMER_NUMBER=1000) (ADDRESS1=issue here (some more text) (ADDRESS2=) (ADDRESS3=) (ADDRESS4=) (CITY=city, ) (STATE=na) (ZIP=250) (COUNTY=) (COUNTRY=NA) (CONTACT_NAME=)

Comment: Have added (3) which assumes that outer parentheses are followed by fixed keywords.

Comment: Is there a way to do this read.dcf approach and within the dplyr piece just append the edited data to the original table row? The output I get from this isn't quite exactly the same # of observations as my original, so I can't just append the columns to the original data.

Comment: Not entirely clear about this problem but maybe you can create a 2 column data frame from the original text and all the text except Customer Number and `join` that to the data frame created in the answer.