# Latex expression replacement in R

Tags: r, regex

I'm working with a LaTex document in R and I need to change `{#1 \over #2}` to `\frac{#1}{#2}`.

With simple expressions like:

- `{1\over 2}`
- `{x^2+y^2\over \lambda}`

I can do it with `stringr::str_replace()` or `gsub` base functions and the regex `\\{([\\^a-z0-9\\\\\\s\\+\\-\\*/\(\)]+)\\s*\\\\over\\s*([\\^a-z0-9\\\\\\s\\+\\-\\*/\(\)]+)\\}` (I guess there has to be a better approach to do this. I tried with `\\{(.+)\\s*\\\\over\\s*(.*)\\}` but it captured more than I wanted.)

But when I work with expressions like:

- `{e^{2c} \over x-1}`
- `{2yz\over 1+x^{2} }`

or a more complicated expression:

- `\\item $Dom\\left(Q\\right)\\ne {\\rm R}^{2} $ y uno de los puntos no pertenecientes al dominio es $\\left({1\\over 2} ,{1\\over 2} \right).$`

the above regex failed.

Is there a regex that can catch all the alternatives? Thanks

Comment: I'd drop regexes for this, and instead find the position of `\over` in the string, then take everything except the first `{` for `#1` and everything except the last `}` for `#2`. Then build the replacement string.

Comment: `paste("\\frac", gsub("\\\\over", "}{", x, perl=TRUE))` seems to work, but sure it will break easily

Comment: You may want to consider extract_LaTeX_argument() from package TeXCheckR.

Comment: @user20650 Interesting solution It is true that it works well, but if we only work with the examples I put above. But those examples are within longer expressions such as for example `\item $\left(K,\left({c\over \lambda K^{\alpha } } \right)^{{1\over \beta } } \right).$`  and there it fails.

Comment: @Hugh I did not know about the existence of that package. I will take a look. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rather enjoyed this question.

At some point you have to parse the document. `parse_tex` from `TeXCheckR` had LaTeX not plain TeX in mind but seems to do okay here. For multi-line instances of `\over` the script would need to be changed though the principle would be the same I think.

The challenge was for continued fractions.

```r
library(data.table) # for shift
library(TeXCheckR)  # for parse_tex

locate_over <- function(doc_parsed) {
  lead <- function(x, n) data.table::shift(x, n = n, type = "lead", fill = "")
  char <- .subset2(doc_parsed, "char")
  which(char == "\\" &
          lead(char == "o", 1L) &
          lead(char == "v", 2L) &
          lead(char == "e", 3L) &
          lead(char == "r", 4L))
}


over2frac <- function(lines, verbose = FALSE) {
  out <- lines
  for (i in seq_along(lines)) {
    if (grepl("\\over", lines[i], fixed = TRUE)) {
      i_parsed <- parse_tex(lines[i])

      # Find lhs
      for (j in locate_over(i_parsed)) {
        lhs_start <- max(which(.subset2(i_parsed, "char") %chin% c("$", "{") &
                                 .subset2(i_parsed, "column") < j &
                                 .subset2(i_parsed, "tex_group") == .subset2(i_parsed[j], "tex_group")))

        rhs_end <- min(which(.subset2(i_parsed, "char") %chin% c("$", "}") &
                               .subset2(i_parsed, "column") > j + 4L &
                               .subset2(i_parsed, "tex_group") == .subset2(i_parsed[j], "tex_group")))

        i_parsed[lhs_start, char := "{\\frac{"]
        i_parsed[rhs_end, char := "}}"]
      }
      res <- paste0(i_parsed[["char"]], collapse = "")
      res <- gsub("\\over", "}{", res, fixed = TRUE)
      out[i] <- res
    }
  }
  out
}
```

Test TeX document:

```tex
$5 \over 2$

This is another fraction: ${1 \over 2}$.

And another:
$$A = a \over b$$

What about:
$${{D \over C} \over H}$$

Finally:

$${e^{2c} \over x-1}$$


${2yz\over 1+x^{2} }$

$$\phi = 1 + {1 \over {1 + {1 \over {1 + {1 \over {1 + \ddots}}}}}}$$

\item $Dom\left(Q\right)\ne {\rm R}^{2} $ y uno de los puntos no pertenecientes al dominio es $\left({1\over 2} ,{1\over 2}\right).$

\bye
```

Resulting LaTeX document: with the necessary LaTeX-specific stuff, plus mandatory math mode for inline fractions. `writeLines(over2frac(readLines("tex1.tex"), verbose = FALSE), "latex1.tex")`

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

${\frac{5 }{ 2}}$

This is another fraction: ${\frac{1 }{ 2}}$.

And another:
${\frac{A = a }{ b}}$

What about:
$${\frac{{\frac{D }{ C}} }{ H}}$$

Finally:

$${\frac{e^{2c} }{ x-1}}$$


${\frac{2yz}{ 1+x^{2} }}$

$$\phi = 1 + {\frac{1 }{ {1 + {\frac{1 }{ {1 + {\frac{1 }{ {1 + \ddots}}}}}}}}}$$

\item $Dom\left(Q\right)\ne {\rm R}^{2} $ y uno de los puntos no pertenecientes al dominio es $\left({\frac{1}{ 2}} ,{\frac{1}{ 2}} \right).$


\end{document}
```

Comment: A little bit more complicated as I expected but it works. Thanks

Comment: Before I forget, you should modify locate over to check that the character after ‘r’ is not a letter (to avoid breaking on \overline etc)

Answer (score 1):

Given some sample strings:

```
> strings
[1] "{1\\over 2}"              "{x^2+y^2\\over \\lambda}"
```

This monster:

```
 > unlist(
      lapply(
         strsplit(
           sub("\\}$","",
              sub("^\\{","",strings)),"\\\\over"),
          function(x){paste0("\\frac{",x[1],"}{",x[2],"}")}))
```

produces:

```
 [1] "\\frac{1}{ 2}"              "\\frac{x^2+y^2}{ \\lambda}"
```

This will break if there's more than one `\over` in the source string. And probably in many other cases too... Oh, it doesn't work if there's spaces before the first `{` or after the closing `}`.

On your other examples you get this:

```
     in                         out                          
[1,] "{1\\over 2}"              "\\frac{1}{ 2}"             
[2,] "{x^2+y^2\\over \\lambda}" "\\frac{x^2+y^2}{ \\lambda}"
[3,] "{e^{2c} \\over x-1}"      "\\frac{e^{2c} }{ x-1}"     
[4,] "{2yz\\over 1+x^{2} }"     "\\frac{2yz}{ 1+x^{2} }"
```

Comment: Interesting solution. It is true that it works well, but if we only work with the examples I put above. But those examples are within longer expressions such as for example \item $\left(K,\left({c\over \lambda K^{\alpha } } \right)^{{1\over \beta } } \right).$ and there it fails. My fault for not having correctly formulated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This gets you most of the way for your examples:

```
library(stringr)

s <- "Expression 1 is {1\\over 2}.

Expression 2 is {x^2+y^2\\over \\lambda}, yes it is.

Expression 3 is {e^{2c} \\over x-1}.

The last expression: {2yz\\over 1+x^{2} }, all done now."

s2 <- str_replace_all(s, 
                      "\\{(.*?)\\s{0,}\\\\over\\s{0,}(.*?)\\}", 
                      "\\frac\\{\\1\\}\\{\\2\\}")

s2
[1] "Expression 1 is frac{1}{2}.\n\nExpression 2 is frac{x^2+y^2}{\\lambda}, yes it is.\n\nExpression 3 is frac{e^{2c}}{x-1}.\n\nThe last expression: frac{2yz}{1+x^{2} }, all done now."
```

The only issue is that a space remains in the last expression, which may not be a problem since it existed in the original:

```
frac{2yz}{1+x^{2} }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that it does not work with the expresion `\\item $Dom\\left(Q\\right)\\ne {\\rm R}^{2} $ y uno de los puntos no pertenecientes al dominio es $\\left({1\\over 2} ,{1\\over 2} \right).$` It is my fault to not be more concrete in my question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This approach can handle:

- multiple {...} containing \over on the same line
- {...} not containing \over
- other text before, after and between occurrences of {...}
- lines not having any {...} with \over

For example, note in the example below the {jjj} on the second input line before the first occurrence of a {...} with \over works as expected.

It makes use of `gsubfn` which can handle balanced parentheses.  First create a proto object `p` similar to the one in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48155729/separating-a-column-in-r-using-regex-separate-tidyr/48156607#48156607).  `p` initializes a counter `k` to 0 and increments it for each { and decrements it for each }.  It replaces any { for which k=1 with ! and also any } for which k=0 with !.

Then replace `!...\over...!` with `\frac{...}{...}` and replace any remaining `!...!` with `{...}`.

We have assumed that ! does not appear in the input but if it does choose a different character.

```
library(gsubfn)
library(magrittr)

# test input
s <- c("abc {1\\over 2} def {x^2+y^2\\over \\lambda} ghi { 12 } XYZ",
       "X {jjj} A {e^{2c} \\over x-1} jkl {2yz\\over 1+x^{2} } Z")

# processing

p <- proto(
 pre = function(.) .$k <- 0,
 fun = function(., x) {
  if (x == "{") .$k <- .$k + 1 else if (x == "}") .$k <- .$k - 1
  if (x == "{" && .$k == 1) "!" else if (x == "}" && .$k == 0) "!" else x
})

s %>%
  gsubfn("[{}]", p, .) %>%
  gsub("!([^!]*)\\\\over ([^!]*)!", "\\\\frac{\\1}{\\2}", .) %>%
  gsub("!([^!]*)!", "{\\1}", .)
```

giving this result:

```
[1] "abc \\frac{1}{2} def \\frac{x^2+y^2}{\\lambda} ghi { 12 } XYZ"
[2] "X {jjj} A \\frac{e^{2c} }{x-1} jkl \\frac{2yz}{1+x^{2} } Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=c("{e^{2c} \\over x-1}","{2yz\\over 1+x^{2} },,dty{k^4e{-rpi/3}\\over\\sqrt{2pik}}")

gsub("\\{(.*?)\\\\over(.*?)\\}","\\\frac{\\1}{\\2}",x)

[1] "\frac{e^{2c} }{ x-1}"                                       
[2] "\frac{2yz}{ 1+x^{2} },,dty\frac{k^4e{-rpi/3}}{\\sqrt{2pik}}"
```

Explanation:

`\{(.*?)\\over(.*?)\\`

- List item{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)

**1st Capturing Group (.*?)**

- .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
- *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

`\\` matches the
   character \ literally (case sensitive) over matches the characters
   over literally (case sensitive)

**2nd Capturing Group (.*?)**

- .*? matches any character (except for line terminators)
- *? Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

`\\` matches the character \ literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The problem is that it does not work with the expresion `\\item $Dom\\left(Q\\right)\\ne {\\rm R}^{2} $ y uno de los puntos no pertenecientes al dominio es $\\left({1\\over 2} ,{1\\over 2} \right).$` It is my fault to not be more concrete in my question. Sorry.

Comment: What does it do?